# Installing a PIR Motion Detector - Not working because it requires a neutral wire

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture, motion-sensor

This is going to make me sound daft but I am new to DIYing and by no means an electrician! But I am trying to install a motion sensor light switch on the ceiling where a pull cord switch used to be.

I have connected the two red live wires and the earth wire but there is no neutral.

As it's not working, my idea of "maybe it won't need it" was obviously wrong. What are my options here as there is no neutral wire? Is there a way round it?

Thank you for any help given!

Comment: Where are you located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several passive infrared switches available that operate without a neutral wire. Yours does not seem to be one of those types. Replacing the switch will be much easier than running a neutral wire to the location.

Search *PIR switch no neutral*.

Comment: Agreed. There are two options 1.) install a neutral wire. 2.) Use a device that doesn't require a neutral.